# Scalar functions performance if they act just as a CASE wrappers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

In our code we have to bring back some concatenated strings in our `SELECT` statements and we have to use `CASE` statement for that. Thing is, we have to do it couple of places and if you need to change something, you have to do it in multiple places as well, which is quite annoyihng.

This looks pretty much like that:

```
SELECT P.ProductID
    , P.Name
    , CASE P.Flag
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Case 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Case 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN CONCAT('Case 3', P.SomeProductColumn)
    END AS Something
FROM dbo.Product AS P;
```

Of course that's oversimplified, but you get the picture. Now I'd like to create a scalar function that would act as a wrapper. Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction
(
    @Flag SMALLINT
    , @SomeProductColumn VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE @Flag
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Case 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Case 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN CONCAT('Case 3', @SomeProductColumn)
    END
END
```

So that I now can execute my query this way:

```
SELECT P.ProductID
    , P.Name
    , dbo.MyFunction(P.Flag, P.SomeProductColumn) AS Something
FROM dbo.Product AS P;
```

It looks not only cleaner, but now I have my column calculation logic encapsulated and it's going to be easier to manage it.

I've been reading a lot that I should be avoiding scalar functions in sql server as they're performance killers, but all (majority) of them cover functions, that query specific tables and that each row calls that function, i.e. 1000 rows would call that function 1000 times and tables would be queried 1000 times as well.

Would approach, I'm looking for, impact query performance in a bad way? I'm not sure how to test that. If this has been already answered, please do not hesitate to link it or mark question as dupe.

Comment: Looked at execution plans and it seems that scalar functions impact performance quite a lot. Like you've suggested, i've replaced scalar function with inline one and used it this way: `CROSS APPLY dbo.MyFunction(P.Flag, P.SomeProductColumn)` and it seems to perform equally to my case statement, which is expected behaviour. Is that correct approach @JamesZ ?

Comment: Yes, UDF does affect performance, even if they don't touch tables. For example, you'll never get a parallel plan with scalar UDF. See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx  Convert it to TVF, if you can: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx

Comment: @VladimirBaranov You're right, I've had a plan where I had parallel plan and once I replaced it with UDF parallelism was gone.

Comment: So did using inline function solve the issue? Or does it still work slower than if you just use the case statement instead?

Comment: @JamesZ Looking at execution plan, seems that it solves problem UDF creates. However I've done just basic testing now with couple of queries, I'll have to do further investigation and check whether it performs well or not. But this looks promising.

Comment: @JamesZ Could you post this as an answer? Did testing with more complex queries and heavier tables and it performs very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both scalar and multi-statement user defined functions are notoriously bad for performance. Although inline user defined functions look almost the same, they don't have the same performance impact and are usually the best way to implement something like this.

The simplest way to check the performance impact of the query is from plan cache, `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` + `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`. The commented part is for showing query plan:

```
select top 50
    SUBSTRING(t.text, (s.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
        ((CASE s.statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.text)
        ELSE s.statement_end_offset
        END - s.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) as statement_text,
    t.text,
    s.total_logical_reads, 
    s.total_logical_reads / s.execution_count as avg_logical_reads,
    s.total_worker_time, 
    s.total_worker_time / s.execution_count as avg_worker_time,
    s.execution_count,
    --,cast(p.query_plan as xml) as query_plan
from 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle) t
    --outer apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (plan_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) p
where 
    t.text like '%something to find your query%'
order by 
    total_logical_reads desc
option (recompile)
```